# Access google cloud data without GCP account

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have created a bucket and files in it with Google Cloud Storage. I have also edited the permissions of the bucket to allow access to persons within a Googlegroup account.

Now, if they need to access the data, do they need to "sign up" at the Google Cloud Platform?

Is there anyway they can copy all the files in the bucket using gsutil again without GCP account?

Answer (score 3):

No, there's not a way to allow access to a bucket in that way, but Google accounts and GCP accounts are the same, so anyone with a gmail account could access it.

The closest thing to your use case is [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), which can grant access to individual objects.